# Escalating privileges of a program from guest account

Tags: windows, privileges, guest-account

Can I esclate privileges of any Windows executable from Guest account to system or administrator?

Do I have to edit the registry or use some script?

Comment: Do you mean you want to give an already running program admin privileges?

Comment: for instance i have cmd shell i want to esclate it to System or Admin from my guest Want some shortcut is it possible

Comment: It depends on your Windows environment. In some cases pressing 'r' while holding the windows key and then typing the name of the executable (such as 'cmd') will run as admin even on Guest accounts.

Comment: Just tell that you want to create a virus and you want to escalate it's privileges to admin to do everything you want =)

Answer (score 2):

There're many exploits and vulnerabilities in different versions of Windows.
You can find a lot of them in internet, just search "windows privilege escalation exploit", and you'll find a lot of them...

Once upon a time there was an exploit kalled Kitrap0d which was exploiting a 0-day vulnerability.
It could escalate privileges to SYSTEM in Windows XP SP2 (and older), or Windows which version is less than 5.1.2600 (yes, it's the same WinXP SP2).
And there're a lot of exploits alike it...

Your question is alike this: "I want to create a virus and I'd like need to gain admin privileges even if my virus was run from Guest. Please, help me!" :)
I think you're going wrong way, because if you continue like this, the next day you'll be in prison:) Be carefull, don't use it for bad purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have legitimate access to an administrative account on the system, you can run a program as that user by selecting "Run as..." from its context menu. You'll then be able to input the credentials of that admin account to run your program at the higher privilege level.

If you don't, well, then you're essentially trying to subvert the security measures that having separate accounts provides in the first place. I won't say this isn't possible, but it's certainly not something you should do unless you own the computer or have permission from the owner of the computer.

Answer (score 1):

This is already a little bit old, but here it goes for future users who search for the same.

If the system is not completely updated, most probably, yes, you can, and there are several ways to escalate privileges, most common are, using vulnerabilities from:

- OS
- Installed software
- Running Services

First you should enumerate your system, to get version, patches, Installed Software, Running Services, ....

Then go to an online platform of vulnerabilities, like https://www.exploit-db.com/ or https://www.cvedetails.com/. In this websites, using the info I mention above that you should enumerate, you can find exploits.
Some of them you can use them directly, for example dirtyc0w exploit is very destructive, makes a lot of noise, but it gets the job done in Linux systems with certain characteristics...